# ng-repeat load data but wont show until i click some button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller and a view in angular.
I am calling a function via ajax to get data from server and then load it in array, then bind it with ng-repeat, it loads the data but wont show until i click any button.
 Following is the codes.
View.

```
<table class="table table-striped" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>Mobile No</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in emplist">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.designation}}</td>
        <td>{{item.mobile}}</td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Controller.

```
angular
.module('MyApp.ctrl.crud', [])
.controller('loginController',[
    '$scope',

    function ($scope) {

        $scope.emplist = [];

        $scope.load = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/Home/getList',
                success: function (data) {
                    $scope.emplist = data;
                    console.log($scope.emplist);
                }
            });
        }

        $scope.load();
```

Comment: I can't see anything particularly wrong with the partial code you've posted - what buttons are you clicking that end up triggering the 'showing' of the results?

Comment: any of the buttons on view, it dosent matter which one i click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try using the $http service of angular for the ajax. If you do so you will not need to explicitly do anything like *$scope.load()*. This may be happening because, the scope is refreshed only after a user action, and only then it has the new scope value. But in case of $http, the scope is auto refreshed when the response is fetched and stored in $scope.

Alternately if you do not want to change your code to $http, then in your success callback to $.ajax do a $scope.$apply() as below:

```
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.emplist = data;
            $scope.$apply();  // or $scope.$digest();
            console.log($scope.emplist);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a get outside of angular. You should probably look into implementing $http.get (instead of using $.ajax, which looks like jquery).

If you MUST use $.ajax then you need to tell angular to $apply like so:

```
$scope.load = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/Home/getList',
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.emplist = data;
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log($scope.emplist);
        }
    });
}
```

Docs on $http.get: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Docs on $apply: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Answer (score 0):

$http is the correct tool to use in this case, it has awareness of angular's two-way data binding and will automatically digest the scope after watched variables have changed.  Here's a simplified version of your controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp.ctrl.crud', [])
.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.emplist = [];
    $http.jsonp('/Home/getList').success(function(data){
        $scope.emplist = data;
    });
});
```